# DATETIME выбрать только по дате (запрос)

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с полем, date с свойством даты и времени, нужно сделать выборку только за одно число, время не интересует. 
Вот так пусто

```
 SELECT `type`, `date`,
 `author_nickname`,
 `target_user_nickname`, `body`,
 `privacy` FROM `pcpin_message_log`
 WHERE ( `privacy` = '0' AND `date` = 
 DATE('2013-04-23') AND
 `target_room_id` = '5' AND `type` IN
 (3001,111,115,10101,10105,10110,10111)
 ) OR ( `room_id` = '5' AND `type` IN
 (10107) ) ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT
 0,100
```

А если убрать `AND date = DATE('2013-04-23')`, или добавить конкретное время, то запрос работает, но нужно за конкретное число.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может

```
 date(`date`)=date('2013-04-23')
```

Comment: Работает , пасиб ))))